# Is it necessary to set up all banking account info in the iPhone dev account before submitting a InAppPurchase free application?

Tags: iphone

I am developing an application in which I have to use in-app purchase feature. I referred to the below links and prepared the sample app.

[http://blog.mugunthkumar.com/coding/iphone-tutorial-–-in-app-purchases/](http://blog.mugunthkumar.com/coding/iphone-tutorial-%E2%80%93-in-app-purchases/)

http://troybrant.net/blog/2010/01/in-app-purchases-a-full-walkthrough/

I followed similar steps which are mentioned in these links, still I am getting the no product id (getting blank value) in

```
-(void)productsRequest:(SKProductsRequest *)request didReceiveResponse:(SKProductsResponse *)response
```

I haven't set up the Bank Info,Contact Info, Tax Info in "iOS Paid Applications". Is this causing any issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you need to sign paid application contract to work with in-app purchase:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#technotes/tn2259/_index.html

Comment: but I am facing invalid productId  issue from apple server

Comment: Just try the steps mentioned here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1471454/storekit-in-app-purchase-invalid-product-identifiers