# In App Purchase works in simulator but not on iPhone

Tags: iphone, in-app-purchase, storekit

When I call SKProductsRequest for an in-app purchase on the Simulator title, description, price and ID all come back correctly from iTunes Connect. When I run it on my device, I get invalid product ID.

Any idea why?

Comment: Try to log the ID you are sending from your device - is it really the right one?

Comment: are you signing your app with the right certificate?

Comment: possible duplicate of [storekit In app purchase invalid product identifiers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1471454/storekit-in-app-purchase-invalid-product-identifiers)

Comment: @tilo, when I change the product ID, the simulator no longer works and returns invalid product ID too. So if it works on the simulator, why not working on the Device too?

Comment: If you delete the app from your iPhone and reinstall, it works. THis matters if you've submitted a previous version of the app for review.

Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you delete the app from your iPhone and reinstall, it works. THis matters if you've submitted a previous version of the app for review. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 3):

I was having same problem. 
I couldn't test it because my iPad was jailbroken.
I removed AppSync, and now it works fine! :)