# InAppPurchase works in simulator but not on iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, app-store, in-app-purchase, storekit

I have an app v1.0 already released on the store without In App Purchase. I develop a v1.1 adding an In App Purchase.

IAP works fine on simulator (title, description, price and ID all come back correctly from iTunes Connect), but not on the device. 
As Eric sayed on this post, a solution is to delete the app from the iphone and reinstall.
[In App Purchase works in simulator but not on iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7837019/in-app-purchase-works-in-simulator-but-not-on-iphone/10922303#10922303) => it works

BUT Question! Will my users also need to uninstall their application v1.0 and install 1.1 for this to work???? (or the problem is just a "sandbox" problem and my users can do an update and have IAP working once time ??)

(it's a big problem for if they need to reinstall because they are going to loose data stored in their v1.0 for update in v1.1 just to have IAP that works...).

Thank you for your help

Comment: As long as the version numbers are different, the app will not need to be removed and reinstalled. I too had the same problem because during testing the version was not changing.

Comment: Changing version during test changes nothing, In App Purchase doesn't work on device => So I have no choice, publish my app, and pray !