# In-app purchase testing issue

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, in-app-purchase

So I am building an iPhone application with in app purchasing, and I'm trying to test it. I think i have followed all of the right instructions:

- Create unique App ID
- Create app using the ID in iTunes Connect
- Add non-consumable purchase item to it (screenshot attached)
- Create provisioning profile with App ID
- Add provisioning profile to XCode 4.2
- Change Bundle Identifier in XCode project to the unique app ID
- Use the correct product identifier in my request (see code below)

SKProductsRequest *request = [[SKProductsRequest alloc] initWithProductIdentifiers: [NSSet setWithObject:@"com.xxxxxx.xxxxxx.testapp1"]];

request.delegate = self;

[request start];

But my productsRequest method is coming back empty. What am I doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [storekit In app purchase invalid product identifiers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1471454/storekit-in-app-purchase-invalid-product-identifiers)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your making a very common mistake I have made myself with in-app-purchases.
You have taken all the right step but you are missing one step.  If you look in the screenshot you can see that the status says ready to submit.  You need to submit the in-app-purchase.  You do this by clicking on the in-app-purchase in the section of iTunes Connect you are in within the screenshot and in this detail view you click the "Submit In-App-Purchase" button in the upper right corner.  This button may be grayed out.  If it is you must upload a binary for your app.  You can reject it right away if you want to.  Once you have done that you can go back to the detail view and click the submit button.

Comment: This seems to be the answer. But is the right way the first part (submit the product) or the second way (use an NSArray instead of an NSSet)?