# iOS - In-App Purchase - Invalid product Identifier

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect, storekit

I am trying to integrate In-App Purchases in my project. I have used a third party library, `SwiftyStoreKit`, as IAP helper.

I'm trying to fetch the information of my In-App products, but always get a response that `Invalid Product Identifiers`

All my agreements are in Effect (Paid and Free). 
Also, My In-App Product status shows `Waiting for Upload`. My App is yet to be release, so I'm testing it in Sandbox Mode.

Following in my code:

```
import UIKit
import StoreKit
import SwiftyStoreKit

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}

override func viewDidAppear(_ _animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(_animated)

    if dataModel.lists.count >= 2 {
        getInfo()
    }
}

func getInfo() {

    NetworkActivityIndicatorManager.NetworkOperationStarted()

    SwiftyStoreKit.retrieveProductsInfo([productIdentifier], completion: { result in

        NetworkActivityIndicatorManager.networkOperationFinished()

        self.showAlert(alert: self.alertForProductRetrievalInfo(result: result))

    })
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check your `productIdentifier`!
It should be the same string as registered in iTunes Connect.
E.g "com.myapp.myPurchase"

Comment: Yes, it is same. Infact, I copied it from iTunes and used it in my code

Comment: @VaibhavJhaveri your status for IAP should be Ready to Submit

Comment: How? There is no button to Submit the IAP

Comment: Delete the app from your device. Then install the app back onto the device using Build & Run with your device tethered to your Mac. It should work now

Comment: Did you complete financial requirements?

Comment: @SivajeeBattina what financial requirements? I have all the contracts in Effect, both for Free and Paid Application

Comment: @VaibhavJhaveri did you upload your app to iTunes Connect?

Comment: Your in-app product status showing as "waiting for upload" right. May be that is the issue. First reject the old binary. Then delete the in app purchase newer version and then re-upload the binary. Doing this may change your status

Comment: @SivajeeBattina here is the screen shot of IAP - http://prntscr.com/euk31t

Comment: Please wait till that status change or else do the above step if that status lasts for a long time

Comment: Ohk. It has been days since the IAP shows Waiting for Upload

Comment: @SivajeeBattina how long does it take for an IAP to get approved?

Comment: It takes almost same time like an app review. It's around 2-3 days

Comment: You don't need an IAP approval to test in sandbox. Go through this checklist http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11387403/inapppurchase-invalid-product-identifiers-possible-reasons

Answer (score 27):

I had the same exact problem, but the solutions above did not work for me.

This is what did:

It turns out I hadn't filled out the proper payments and W9 form on AppStoreConnect.

Go to AppStoreConnect > Agreements, Tax, and Banking...

Fill out the "Paid Apps" contract if it hadn't already been filled out

[image: AppstoreConnect Contract]

Comment: In most cases, this is an error to fix.

Comment: I just found out my agreement was expired.

Answer (score 4):

This is what worked for me:

I was confusing the reference name ( left side ) with the Product ID ( right side )

So make sure that you're using iTunes Connect's Product ID in your code.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I had the exact same error and running this code in the app delegate seemed to fix my problem because by adding your app's observer at launch ensures that it will persist during all launches of your app, thus allowing your app to receive all the payment queue notifications.

```css
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
 // see notes below for the meaning of Atomic / Non-Atomic
 SwiftyStoreKit.completeTransactions(atomically: true) { purchases in
     for purchase in purchases {
         switch purchase.transaction.transactionState {
         case .purchased, .restored:
             if purchase.needsFinishTransaction {
                 // Deliver content from server, then:
                 SwiftyStoreKit.finishTransaction(purchase.transaction)
             }
             // Unlock content
         case .failed, .purchasing, .deferred:
             break // do nothing
         }
     }
 }
    return true
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you add the "In-App Purchase" to your project from Xcode - Target - Signing & Capabilities.

Answer (score 1):

Remember to make your In-App `Ready To Submit` status.

[image]

If your In-App has different status, then it always return `invalid product identifier`.

Answer (score 1):

Try use productid instead of com.yourname.projectname.productid