# Using Apple In-App Purchase in development mode

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect

I am trying to use Apple In-App purchase in my application's development mode. I have created test In-App product on iTunes connect (Ready to Submit) and trying to fetch product identifiers in my code but its saying **invalid identifier**

Please tell me that how i can test In-App purchase in development mode (app not submitted to live yet)

Steps i have used

1. created In-App product on my iTunes connect account which have
   status **Ready to Submit**
2. enabled In-App purchase in my Xcode project
3. using iAPHelper class downloaded from here -
   https://github.com/saturngod/IAPHelper
4. using following code to access products

But its returning my product id as invalid identifier. don't know what wrong i am doing.

```
if(![IAPShare sharedHelper].iap) {
    NSSet* dataSet = [[NSSet alloc] initWithObjects:@"com.mydomain.app.test", nil];
    [IAPShare sharedHelper].iap = [[IAPHelper alloc] initWithProductIdentifiers:dataSet];
}

[IAPShare sharedHelper].iap.production = NO;

[[IAPShare sharedHelper].iap requestProductsWithCompletion:^(SKProductsRequest* request,SKProductsResponse* response)
 {
     if(response > 0 ) {
         SKProduct* product =[[IAPShare sharedHelper].iap.products objectAtIndex:0];
         NSLog(@"Price: %@",[[IAPShare sharedHelper].iap getLocalePrice:product]);
         NSLog(@"Title: %@",product.localizedTitle);
 }];
```

Comment: It's possible. Follow iOS documentation and tutorials and come with a detailed question; currently it's to vague.

Comment: I have updated my question with more detail

Comment: @DineshKumarVyas you need to have app in Sandbox environment. Follow steps mentioned in official document https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnectInAppPurchase_Guide/Chapters/TestingInAppPurchases.html

Comment: @AmodGokhale i followed all steps but still responding with invalid identifiers.

Comment: @DineshKumarVyas Are your bank details active on iTunes Connect?

Comment: @RakeshJangid thanks my friend, i will update these details and then try again. hope this will work for me.

Answer (score 0):

This is working for me

The contract for paid applications must be in effect in order to receive data about the in app purchases configured.

This worked for me. I had the exact same problem.

check : https://stackoverflow.com/a/2045064/3901620

Comment: I am still receiving invalid identifiers for my product list.