# In App Purchase invalidProductIdentifier in 30% times why ?

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase

I've configured IAP for my project and It seems to work, so my app is live on app store but I've discovered that approximately 30% requests to iTunes returning invalidProductIdentifier for some reason, below is the complete code:

```
class IAP: NSObject, SKProductsRequestDelegate {

    static let sharedInstance = IAP()

    func productsRequest(request: SKProductsRequest, didReceiveResponse response: SKProductsResponse) {
        response.invalidProductIdentifiers.forEach() { id in
            //here is the part that could fail sometimes
            print(id)
        }
    }

    //here how I setup IAP
    func canMakePayments() {
        if(SKPaymentQueue.canMakePayments()) {
            var productID = NSSet()
            productID = NSSet(object: "unlock")
            let request: SKProductsRequest = SKProductsRequest(productIdentifiers: productID as! Set<String>)
            request.delegate = self
            request.start()
        }
    }
}
```

And here how I use it from `AppDelegate`:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
        IAP.sharedInstance.canMakePayments()
        return true
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

If you receive invalidProductIdentifiers on your test device there may be tons of reasons why this happens. The most frequent cases are:

- app was not reinstalled from scratch before checking: you need to
  delete app from device and install it again;
- old product IDs: if you have product IDs that are invalid, they will appear in invalidProductIdentifiers;
- jailbroken device: remove AppSync from Cydia to debug on jailbroken device;
- using provisioning profile that is not associated with explicit App ID.

You can find more reasons [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1041656/iphone-storekit-invalid-product-ids).
Nevertheless invalid product IDs issue on test device doesn't necessary mean that your users experience that problem too.

Comment: but my app is live, and IAP is already live, and its only returning invalidProductIdentifiers in approximately 30% of cases  ...

Comment: I see the point now. This error can be seen at jailbroken devices. Probably that 30 percent uses jailbroken devices.

Answer (score 1):

If you have appstore version of that application in your test device and you are trying to debug that IAP on same device, this may cause this. Please un-install apstore version of app before trying anything.
Second possible problem is, you should check IAP with USB cable plugged in. You cant test it with Ad-hoc deployment.

Also I found a great link to check all possible failures:

http://troybrant.net/blog/2010/01/invalid-product-ids/

Comment: I'm getting this data from the analytics, still have the problem