# In-App Purchase invalid product identifiers in swift 4

Tags: swift, in-app-purchase

It has been a long time chasing the problem within my in-app purchase trials yet I can not seem to solve this issue.My product identifier keeps returning as "invalid product identifier". Hopefully someone will point it out.

```
@IBAction func btnRemoveAdsAction() {

    NetworkActivityIndicatorManager.NetworkOperationStarted()
    SwiftyStoreKit.purchaseProduct("ProductID", completion: {
        result in
        NetworkActivityIndicatorManager.networkOperationFinished()

            if product.needsFinishTransaction {
                SwiftyStoreKit.finishTransaction(product.transaction)
            }
            self.showAlert(alert: self.alertForPurchaseResult(result: result))
        }
    })

}
```

when press on button click and execute above code that will return in completion of method with "result" are always return error("invalid product identifier") and exist from the method.

Comment: Have you entered correct ProductID ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [iPhone StoreKit - invalid product id's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1041656/iphone-storekit-invalid-product-ids)

Comment: what is ProductID ? you need to create identifire for inapp Purchase in itunes connect under your application first and you need to use that instead of ProductID. please search proper tutorial.

Comment: Yes, I enter correct id but still issue

Answer (score 4):

1. Your productID should look more like **com.myappname.funnygame.100coins**. Just mentioning to be sure this is 100% setup as in iTunes connect.
2. Complete your **agreement for paid apps** in iTunes connect 'Agreements, Tax and Banking' tab. Without it you will receive 'invalid product identifier' every time.

[Screenshot of Agreements, Tax and Banking in iTunes connect.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mMWx9.png)